# Windows scripting language

Tags: windows, scripting, login-script

In my current environment, I've implemented a login script system that uses Kixscript. I'm able to drop any kix script in the appropriate directory, after which the login script parsed that directory and executes each script.

I've noticed a decrease in the amount of people documenting/developing for KIX, as well as a lack of 64-bit functionality (not necessary, but nice to have).  Therefore, I'm curious if there is anything that can be recommended (other than WSH or PowerShell) that would be easy to use/implement and be efficient.  Maybe Lua??

FYI, I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104886/universal-scripting-language-for-windows), but it's about 2 years old, so I'm looking for new input without "threadjacking".

Thanks

Comment: You need to give us some requirements to answer this. For starters, why are WSH and PowerShell not acceptable?

Comment: one of the things I've liked about KIX over the years is its relative simplicity to the others.  WSH may work in this case, but having to install an extra interpreter, e.g. Perl or Python (usually a large chunk of space) on each machine tends to bog our systems down.  Kix was a small executable and a dll for graphics, nothing more.  I believe something similar can be done with LUA and Haskell, but I'm still verifying as of this afternoon.  Another reason against WSH is that JS and VB tend to bog down in execution occasionally.  I've never had big lag with any of my Kix scripts

Comment: Well... Finding the right tool for the job requires knowledge of the job. What are you doing with your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VBScript? Support is built into Windows.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know they were one and the same. I don't know that much about Windows (even though I use it lol).